# DataBase query with where

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to mobile application design , I am trying to design an android , I use a database sqlite , my only problem is the query
I have a table and I want to select all the  names in this table whose id is 1

I'm tried this, but I know it's totaly false!

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT" +KEY_ARRET +" FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "where _idligne "  = ' " +1+ '";

   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Thank you for your help !  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_ARRET + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE _idligne = 1";
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

try this way, less lines but is the same, without the mistake of course:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+ KEY_ARRENT+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+"WHERE _idligne = 1", null);
```

in case it dosen't works try this one:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE _idligne = 1", null);
String C1="";
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {//recorre todos los datos/campos
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    C1 = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(KEY_ARRENT));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());//pasa al sig dato /campo
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
```